# DNS fails on google chrome and microsoft edge with err_connection_timed_out

Tags: google-chrome, browser, dns, microsoft-edge

I deployed an app created with reactjs in a linux container on a private server, which was assigned a DNS to access it as follows

```
http://dns:port
```

I have tried to access it with google chrome and microsoft edge from a remote server, a local pc and a mobile device and the answer is always

```
err_connection_timed_out
```

Whereas if I try to access using the server's ip as follows

```
http://server-ip:port
```

It allows me to access the application

The only browsers that allow me to enter the address using DNS are Mozilla and Opera

How can I solve this and why it happens

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I think there might be some settings in Chrome/Edge which prevents DNS working in it. You can try to access the DNS in Chrome/Edge with InPrivate mode to see if it can work. Browsing data such as cookies, app data, cache files, etc. which may lead to the error, you can clear browsing data and test again. Besides, please disable/remove all the browser extensions and test again.

Comment: apparently the problem comes from the server because when I point the dns from the front-end to the back-end I have the same problem

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions I mentioned in my first comment? If the problem comes from the server, why it works with Mozilla and Opera? I have no idea of how the server is set. I think you can check the server configurations to see if there's anything related with browsers.